# An error occurred while submitting the Latex manuscript

Tags: errors

I am submitting a manuscript to bioinfomatics.But there was an error that the format could not be converted("The file failed conversion and will not be available as part of the proof“). An error is reported in the compilation log: LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps. This error does not appear when I do not insert the .eps file in the .tex file.

thank you all

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! There seems to be a problem with the bounding box. Are you allowed to convert the .eps file to .pdf? A tool lieke `epspdftk` usually does that nicely.

Comment: @Mico: I happen to answer on both sites. Must have been out  of my mind… Won't do it again, sworn promise!

Comment: I was just giving you a hard time...

Comment: ae you sre you want to use latex rather than pdflatex, it seems that you are using latex, but google  suggested the file is https://git.metabarcoding.org/lecasofts/ProcMod/blob/manuscript/manuscript/OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps  and I tried including that with latex and it was included without error. the bounding box is `%%BoundingBox: 0 0 54 54` so you could also use `\includegraphics[bb=0 0 54 54]{OUP_First_SBk_Bot_8401.eps}` but that should not be needed